# "Родина-мать" и "Русь-матушка" один образ или разные?

Tags: семантика, история

Родина-мать и Русь-матушка - это разные образы или один и тот же? Если разные, то чем по вашему они различаются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально образ один - **родина** — отвлечённое понятие, характеризующее общественные, националыю-политические отношения,которое  материализуется, развертывается в образе очень близкого любому человеку существа — матери, но в то же время  разные. Родина - слово универсальное, Русь - подчёркивается древность, героическое прошлое страны, Россия - более позднее название , но суть одна, фольклорная.Русь-матушка,матушка Россия,Россия-матушка, матушка
Русь — это **неофициальная, светская национальная** персонификация России.

Русь-матушка-задушевный оттенок, теплота.

Родина-мать - высокое слово, официоз, призыв, плакат.

Этот образ претерпел изменения в процессе развития, может, потому и воспринимается как два разных.

Идея «Руси-матушки» берет начало в фольклорном образе Матери-сырой земли — русском варианте Великой Богини-матери. В XVI веке она приобретает вид Святорусской матери-земли (Святой Руси) под влиянием работ Максима Грека и Андрея Курбского. « Прогрызли они чрево у матери своей, святой русской земли, что породила и воспитала их поистине на беду свою и запустение! Князь А. Курбский о сторонниках Иоанна Грозного»] Российская империя В петровскую эпоху для обозначения государства чаще используется термин «Отечество», однако и образ России-Матери появляется в текстах Феофана Прокоповича и Гавриила Бужинского, а позднее В. Тредиаковского и М. Ломоносова. В последующие два столетия образ получает широкое распространение в литературе.

Выражение "Родина-мать" бытовало в русском языке еще в XIX веке, например, оно встречается в поэме Некрасова "Саша". Это русское богатырство - служение царственной царице-матери.  Культ Родины-матери в той  или иной степени развит во всех странах, с должным чувством самосознания и развитой культурой,образ Родины - матери у НАС стоит в основании всего, потому что изначально связан с образом Богородицы.  С ликом Богородицы шли в бой, рубили врагов. Образ  матери-земли -  в борьбе Невского с немцами, когда уже собирался потихоньку образ Родины как женщины. Этот образ лишь усилился после Куликовской битвы, и уже в Московскую Русь образ Родины прямо воспринимался как женский, он прямо ассоциировался с образом Богородицы - покровительницы и защитницы земли русской.

В период Октябрьской революции и Гражданской войны образ Родины-матери активно включается в пропаганду сторонников Белого движения" И воинство с ‘красной звездою’ Приняв роковую печать, К кресту пригвождает с хулою Несчастную Родину-Мать!" С. Бехтеев

В идеологии большевизма  («Пролетарии не имеют отечества») образ России-матушки игнорировался или же использовался как символ отсталости царской России, её косности, а также национального гнёта. В советскую пропаганду материнский образ страны возвращается в образе Советской Родины-Матери, ставшем ключевым элементом советского патриотизма.

В отличие от дореволюционной «России-Матушки» Советская Родина представлена как мать всех народов СССР.

В период Великой Отечественной войны, начало которой ознаменовалось появлением плаката И. Тоидзе «Родина-мать зовёт!», ставшего символом своего времени.

Силу и непобедимость СССР символизировал другой лик Родины-Матери — воительницы с мечом в руках (монументы в Волгограде, Киеве, Калининграде).

Постсоветский период Распад СССР сопровождался деконструкцией символов советской эпохи, включая Родину-Мать, что отразилось в возникновении альтернативных женских образов России.

Оппозиция 1990-х активно использовала образ униженной России-Матушки для критики «антинародного» режима Б. Ельцина.

Для 2000-х годов характерны «реабилитация» властью образа России-Матушки и включение его во внутриполитическую и внешнеполитическую пропаганду.

Answer (score 2):

Родина-мать использовалась в советской пропаганде для обозначения СССР. Русь-матушка в советской пропаганде практически не встречалась по очевидной причине: СССР - не Русь, к тому же, пропаганда рассчитывалась не только на русских, но и на жителей других республик.

Соответственно, образ Родины-матери был этнически нейтральным, а образ Руси-матушки обычно ассоциируется с русским национальным костюмом, кокошником и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Разные, по-моему. Родина-мать - строгая, не тёплая, даже авторитарная. Русь матушка - тёплая, добрая, не авторитарная и даже не строгая... Это то, что сразу приходит в голову.